# Uniq --count doesn't work properly

Tags: grep, cat, uniq

I'm trying to solve a problem with counting IPs using uniq -c.

My file after using file looks like this :

```
69.246.75.77
7.44.104.171
195.82.180.9
195.82.180.9
61.115.160.23
56.240.142.58
195.82.180.9
87.22.27.189
56.240.142.58
211.114.204.171
204.55.182.16
242.113.24.81
196.34.105.115
28.74.152.20
161.130.133.151
8.89.127.206
175.173.236.111
```

But after using uniq -c I got a result:

```
  1 69.246.75.77
  1 7.44.104.171
  2 195.82.180.9
  1 61.115.160.23
  1 56.240.142.58
  1 195.82.180.9
  1 87.22.27.189
  1 56.240.142.58
  1 211.114.204.171
  1 204.55.182.16
  1 242.113.24.81
  1 196.34.105.115
  1 28.74.152.20
  1 161.130.133.151
  1 8.89.127.206
  1 175.173.236.111
```

So looking at for example 195.82.180.9 I got it 2 times, first with 2 and second with 1 number of occurences. Why doesn't it work as expected?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Uniq will only detect identical entries if they are adjacent (ie consecutive lines) - so you will need to sort the data before running uniq to get the true number of occurrences.